# Simple counter example with spring-cloud-dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm exploring spring-cloud-dataflow and I could successfully walk through the [twitterstream sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/blob/master/analytics/twitter-analytics/README.adoc) and the field-value-counters contained some useful values.

But I fail to create other simple examples like:

`stream create test --definition 'http --server.port=9999 | counter --name=httpcounter --store=redis' --deploy`

or

`stream create http-log --definition 'http --server.port=1234 | log' --deploy`

`stream create http-tap-counter --definition ':http-log.http > counter --name=http-tap-counter' --deploy`

In both cases, the stream gets created and deployed and `stream list` shows them, but the counter does not show up when doing a 'counter list' in the shell.

I also verifies in the logs that the http source is receiving some input.

Any ideas why I am missing here to create a simple counter?

Answer (score 1):

We recently addressed an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/pull/249) with `counter` sink and the fix is now ported over to [stream-app-starters](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters). This fix was included in the recent [1.0.0.M3 release](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/29/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-0-0-m3-released), too.

Please try the latest and let us know if you're still seeing issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After updating spring-cloud-dataflow from the git repository today, the samples now work for me.